# Calculate 3D vector perpendicular to a plane generated by two vectors

Tags: math, 3d, geometry

I am new to dealing with 3D, and even simple stuff makes my head spin around. Sorry for the newbie question.

Lets say I have 2 vectors:

```
a(2,5,1)
b(1,-1,3)
```

These vectors "generate" a plane. How can I get a third vector perpendicular to both **a** and **b**?

I can do this in 2D using a vector c(A,B) and turning it into c'(-B,A).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [cross product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html).

That is, a vector perpendicular to `a` and `b` is given by `( a.y*b.z - a.z*b.y, a.z*b.x - a.x*b.z, a.x*b.y - a.y*b.x)`.

Answer (score 7):

You take the cross multiplication of these two vectors to get a third perpendicular vector to the plane they generate:

```
P = A * B
```

Which is:

```
<xp, yp, zp> = |i   j   k |
               |xa  ya  za| // The determinant
               |xb  yb  zb|
```

All what you have to do is to solve this determinant or just look it up in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) :)

Comment: I like this answer better because it explains where the answer comes from. Not just a random formula to remember.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, here's a cross product function from Quake 3, with vec3_t defined as an array of three floats for x, y, and z:

```
void CrossProduct( const vec3_t v1, const vec3_t v2, vec3_t cross ) {
    cross[0] = v1[1]*v2[2] - v1[2]*v2[1];
    cross[1] = v1[2]*v2[0] - v1[0]*v2[2];
    cross[2] = v1[0]*v2[1] - v1[1]*v2[0];
}
```